# php range of numbers

Tags: php, integer, range

I have the following two numbers 01850 and 01899. I need to get the range of this and store each entry as its own element in an array.

Since these above are integers the range function will not work since it will remove the leading zero. And I have no idea if there will be two leading zeroes or just one.

```
$r1 = '0150';
$r2 = '0159';

$range = range($r2, $r1);

var_dump($range);
```

The above will return 150 - 159 but I need them zeroes!
Does anyone have an idea of how we can do this?

Comment: As you said `since the numbers start with a leading 0` they are considered strings. So use string functions.

Comment: They can start without them aswell, I did not fill that in properly.

Comment: You should have started with that: In that case, just check if there is a leading zero. If there is one, remove it and add it later on to the variable, that had it in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pads all numbers with the width of the high number, so will still play nice for ranges like `090 -> 110`.

```
function rangepad($low, $high)
{
    $range = range($low, $high);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($range); $i++) {
        $range[$i] = str_pad( $range[$i], strlen($high), '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
    }
    return $range;
}

$r1 = '0150';
$r2 = '0159';

var_dump(rangepad($r1, $r2));
```

**Output:**

```
array(10) { [0]=> string(4) "0150" [1]=> string(4) "0151" [2]=> string(4) "0152" 
            [3]=> string(4) "0153" [4]=> string(4) "0154" [5]=> string(4) "0155" 
            [6]=> string(4) "0156" [7]=> string(4) "0157" [8]=> string(4) "0158" 
            [9]=> string(4) "0159" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the zeros afterwards:

```
$r1 = '0150';
$r2 = '0159';

$range = range($r2, $r1);
if (preg_match('~^0+~', $r1, $match)) {
    $range = array_map(function($item) use($match) {
        return $match[1] . $item; 
    }, $range);
}
var_dump($range);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like the following?

```
$r1 = '0150';
$r2 = '0159';

$range = array_map(function($n) { return '0'.$n;}, range($r2, $r1));

var_dump($range);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you must use range(), but if you can use something else try this:

```
for($i = 150; $i < 160; $i++ )
    $range[] = '0'.$i;
var_dump($range);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pad the zeros to keep the number length, like this:

```
function padZero($n)
{
    //make the number length 4, like 0159
    return str_pad ( $n, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
}

$range = array_map ( 'padZero', $range );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not achieve that directly as it is an integer numbers, use array_map function like this,

```
$r1 = '0150';
$r2 = '0159';

function f($number) { 
    return sprintf("%04d", $number); 
}
$response = array_map(f, range($r1, $r2));
print_r($response);
```